# How to set current default font-families to websites in Chromium?

Tags: chromium

I would like to set a default `font-family` in Chromium. I want to make a Chinese font `!important` for all the pages.

Answer (score 3):

Cick on the "tools spanner" in the top right then click on Preferences.

From here click on "Under the Botnet" and then "Customize fonts".

The screenshot below is from Chromium 10 Beta, in earlier versions the dialogues will look a little different.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I want to make a Chinese font `!important` for all the pages.

Comment: @janoChen You might want to edit your question to make that explicit

Answer (score 1):

You can change the font in chromium from preferences > under the hood > change font and languages settings. Won't that do ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder by running `mkdir .config/chromium/Default/User\ StyleSheets/` and into this put a file called **Custom.css** containing your modifications much in the same way that Firefox has **userChrome.css**. Any changes you make will be immediately processed by Chromium, unlike Firefox. This feature was made available around the beginning of this year.

Answer (score 0):

Add the appropriate CSS to your custom userstyle, which is usually located at $HOME/.config/chromium/Default/User Stylesheets/Custom.css.